# JQuery DatePicker - Exluding a dynamic range of dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using the following function, but wish to exclude the last 20 days from my date picker

So a user may:-

Pick any future date in the next year

may pick any date more than 20-365 days ago

but may not select a date between today and 20 days ago.

I'm not sure how to exclude the past 20 days, any help appreciated.

```
  $(function () {

      $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 

    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate: '365',
    minDate: '-365'
});

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeShowDay` method of the datepicker allows you to run a function and return false if you don't want the day to be selectable.

See the API Documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

```
$(function () {

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    maxDate: '365',
    minDate: '-365',
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      //Get current timestamp
      var current = new Date().getTime();
      //Get timestamp for 20 days ago
      var timestamp = current - (20 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      return [!(date.getTime() > timestamp && date.getTime() < current)];
    }
  });

});
```

So the code above should allow the user to pick dates between 365 days ago and 365 days ahead, excluding the previous 20 days.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aka1s8p0/

Comment: Sorry, had a slight error in my code, it should now work.

Comment: Glad to be of help! If you're happy with the answer please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives us both some rep. There is no obligation to do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple solution like this, and you can ofc add more properties to your .datepicker

```js
$(function () {
            var someDate = new Date();
            var dd = someDate.getDate() + 20;
            var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var y = someDate.getFullYear();

            var someFormattedDate = y + ',' + mm + '/' + dd;
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                inline: true,
                minDate: new Date(someFormattedDate)
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Comment: This doesn't allow the selection of days more than 20 days ago?